# 3 Step process for Web: 1 single long page versus 3 separate pages

Tags: hierarchy, page-layout

Im designing a x3 step process for the web

Should i have it on one long page
1.
2.
3.

Or move users to the next ] page
1. (Next:Do 2)
2. (Next: Do 3)
3  (Finish)

Comment: What is the purpose of the process? Who are the users? How long is each step? What are the steps?

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail here. If the 3 steps are 'Name', 'Email' and 'Phonenumber' then that's clearly better as one page. But if the steps are 'Complete medical history', 'Financial transactions of the last 5 years' and 'Family tree of the past 4 generations' then splitting it over several pages is better.

Answer (score 1):

If there's indeed enough content to fill one long page with it, then splitting it into several shorter pages might be beneficial. Users won't feel overwhelmed by the amount of content (or by the amount of data that is asked of them, in case this is a big form) and they'll have a better sense of progress.

In that case just make sure to provide some kind of a progress indicator, so that users have an approximate idea of how long of a process are they committing to.

Some examples:

- http://ui-patterns.com/users/16410/collections/4853
- http://ui-patterns.com/users/10302/collections/2439

Also, a good read on the subject: http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/StepsLeft

Comment: I don't think it is worth answering questions that are this poor.  There is no way to give a good answer based on the information given.

Comment: Agreed, will refrain from doing so in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree on most suggestions for a progress wizard (there is a related post [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64473/the-effect-of-showing-wizard-style-steps-in-a-multistep-process/64508#64508)).

I do not completly agree, that the amount of content is critical if it should be splitted in serveral pages. Think of pinterest for example. They have an endless page to scroll. For sure there are some withdrawals with the automatic appending of new content (perceived size/position of the site).

But users are used to scrolling and the effort is very low (flick with the finger, scrollwheel). Especially when the user wants to have a "look back". Switching to a different page/slide, needs more effort/load time.

So to break it down for you question: If you have separate steps, which probably need some explaination, paging would do a good job.
If you have a lot of content, maybe connected together, consider if putting them on a page, with dynamic feedback of progress in the steps would fit in (think of a timeline/stream).

Hope this helps to find the right question ;)